# Should I be using Data Access and Business Logic inside my BLL class when using Linq To SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-access-layer, business-logic-layer

I am using `ASP.NET Web Forms/C#`.

I researched about implementing `BLL` and `DLL` in my application.

I found out that many say that using `Linq To SQL` replaces `DAL` itself.

So you should be accessing Data and implementing Business Logic inside the `BLL` class itself.Not sure if it is correct.

Currently I have a class `CustomerBLL`.I am accessing the data and implementing Business Logic inside it.

So my question is,is it a good approach?

Can I follow this?

Also currently I have only one `BLL` class , should I use only one or one per `.aspx` page or group similar pages together.

Here is my `CustomerBLL.cs`(Just including few functions).

```
namespace CwizBankApp
{
    public class CustomerBLL
    {
        public string GetDateFormat()
        {
            using (var db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
            {
                var format = db.CODEs.Where(code => code.NAME.Equals("dateformat")).Select(code=>code.DRNAME) .SingleOrDefault();  
                return format;   
            }
        }

        public IList<string> GetAccountTypes()
        {
            using (var db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
            {
                var  acctype = db.mem_types.Select(account=>account.CustCategory).Distinct().ToList();
                return acctype;
            }
        }




        public IList<mem_city> GetCities(int index)
        {
            using (var db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
            {
                var city = db.mem_cities.Where(c => c.state_id.Equals(index)).ToList();
                return city;
            }
        }

        public string InsertDate(string datefield,string dateFormat)
        {
            string dd, mm, yyyy;
            string date;
            string [] split = Regex.Split(datefield, @"/");
            yyyy = split[2];
            if (dateFormat.Equals("British"))
            {
                dd = split[0];
                mm = split[1];
            }
           else
            {
                dd = split[1];
                mm = split[0];
            }

            date = mm.PadLeft(2, '0') + "/" + dd.PadLeft(2, '0') + "/" + yyyy;  
            return date;
        }

        public string RetrieveDate(string datefield,string dateFormat)
        {
            string dd, mm, yyyy;
            string date;
            string [] split = Regex.Split(datefield, @"/");
            dd = split[1];
            mm = split[0];
            yyyy = split[2];

            if (dateFormat == "British")
            {
                date = dd.PadLeft(2, '0') + "/" + mm.PadLeft(2, '0') + "/" + yyyy;   
            }
            else
            {
                date = mm.PadLeft(2, '0') + "/" + dd.PadLeft(2, '0') + "/" + yyyy;   
            }
            return date;
        }
}
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general I separate the BL from the DAL, so that the DAL needs a reference to the BL. This means the BL contains POCO's and an interface that describes the repository/unit-of-work/... So to answer your question, yes, I would still create a DAL which would use L2S.

To answer you second question, I would create one business object per entity that exist in your domain. Usually this matches with the tables in your DAL. The code-behind of your aspx contains the logic of your page, not the business layer.

Comment: Any article links or a simple example will be a huge help.Thanks.

Comment: I'll see if I can cook one up myself, but I can't give a projection on when.